# The magic behind the executable jar?

Tags: java, jar

Jar is a convenient way to use java, as every class can be included in one jar.

I use antlr as follows, and it calls jar using -jar option.

```
java -jar $ANTLRDIR/antlr-3.2.jar ANTLR_CODE.g
```

And, this is the command that calls clojure. Instead of calling clojure.jar using -jar option. It's in the -cp, and calls some 'function'.

```
java -cp $CLOJURE_JAR:$CLASSPATH clojure.lang.Script CLOJURE_CODE.clj
```

#### Questions

- What's the magic behind this method? What's 'clojure.lang.Script'?
- Can the antlr be called with the same way? If so what's the name that should be used (something like clojure.lang.Script)?
- How about the jar file made with other languages : clojure/scala? How do I know the name that should be called?
- What's the difference between the two methods? Pros and cons?

Comment: Note that you might get more directed help from the SO community by asking individual questions per Question, rather than a whole block of questions. That way, there is one Right Answer possible for each.

Comment: Has been awhile since I have done Java, but I believe that, you can instruct `javac` (usually with the help of something like `ant` or an IDE) to compile a `jar` with a default class selected to run when you try to run it, or double-click it. However, you can also have more controls and run things directly. I believe `jar` is just a fancy zip + some Java-specific stuff, so you can treat the contents of that file as a directory easily. So then it is like executing `clojure.lang.Script.class` that is in your path somewhere. I am not sure about the function of `$1` though.

Comment: I assume that you are on a *nix environment. Step 1: locate `$ANTLRDIR/antlr-3.2.jar`. Step 2: unzip `$ANTLRDIR/antlr-3.2.jar` into its own directory. Step 3: Look at the contents of that directory, see if you can locate `clojure/lang/Script.class` or something like that, see if you can run it. Step 4: type `man java` on command line. Step 5: Java hacker level +1.

Comment: the jar method will only work with executable jars.  The advantage being you don't need to know the name of the class with 'main' (i.e., clojure.lang.Script).  An executable jar is basically a jar that defines the class with 'main' in its MANIFEST.MF file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

•What's the magic behind this method? What's 'clojure.lang.Script'?

clojure.lang.Script is the class with the main method that the jar executable is running.

•Can the antlr be called with the same way? If so what's the name that should be used (something like clojure.lang.Script)?

The antlr jar can be called the same way. You have to know the name of the main class (which is in the MANIFEST.MF file in the jar.)

•How about the jar file made with other languages : clojure/scala? How do I know the name that should be called?

I don't know... Probably depends on the language.

•What's the difference between the two methods? Pros and cons?

Executable jars are very easy for users to launch (especially in Windows). Just a double click on the jar file.

•In this post, I was told that -jar ignores all the -cp and $CLASSPATH. Why is this? Is there any reason for this?

No doubt the Sun guys did this for security reasons.

•I was also told -cp option also ignores the $CLASSPATH. Why is this? Is there any good reason for this?

The -cp option overrides the $CLASSPATH. That's the whole purpose of this option.

Comment: -cp overrides, but wouldn't this syntax explicitly include it?

Comment: Yes, since he includes $CLASSPATH in his -cp, it would include his $CLASSPATH. The purpose of the -cp $CLOJURE_JAR:$CLASSPATH is that anything in the clojure jar is first before anything else in the classpath.